# class not found exception Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") in webservice

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, classnotfoundexception

I have a problem and need help in `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` that throw class not found exception when i run webservice from eclipse ,but when I create new java project its run perfectly.

I add the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.19-bin.jar` in the build path for both projects 
but I don't know what is the problem in the webservice.

```
  public String insertOrder(
         int current_id, 
        int table_id) 
        {
            try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection con = 
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myhoteldb", "root", "mypassword");
      PreparedStatement st = 
    con.prepareStatement("insert into orders(orders.current_id,orders.table_id) values(?,?)");
      st.setInt(1, current_id);
      st.setInt(2, table_id);

      st.executeUpdate();
      } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
      return "record inserted";
      }
    }
```

and this the error log

```
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at pkg.MyServices.insertOrder(MyServices.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:194)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:102)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:173)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:144)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: When you export your .war file, is the .jar included?

Comment: @Michael's comment is why it's good during dev to use exploded war files, so you have visibility into what is actually there.

Comment: Hardik is right. Basically the issue is that even though the Jar is there in the class path, the server is not able to find and access it and hence the excpetion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If this code works in your J2SE it means you need to have a JAR file somewhere containing `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class (so called JDBC driver). This JAR needs to be visible in Tomcat.  So, I would suggest to place `mysql-jdbc.jar` at physical location to `/WEB-INF/lib` directory of your project.

Many times in the past, I have experienced `ClassNotFoundException` if jar is not at physical location. Then restarting Tomcat should work.

Comment: Mishar ,Thanks for your answer this solve my problem :)) many thanks for all

Comment: thanks it worked by copying on web-inf /lib and this probelm on web service on eclipse but on netbeans it worked just fine i used axis2 on java file

Comment: great one bro solve my issue to ..