# Tomcat gives 404 when i call my servlet

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I can't access to my servlet i call with a form. I checked the arborescence, web.xml and the form, but i can't see any problem. I use Eclipse with a "web dynamic project".

There is my arborescence :

[image]

My web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Z-ProjetJ2EE</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
  <description></description>
  <servlet-name>CommandeServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>controleur.CommandeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CommandeServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/urlCommandeServ</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My form (i tried the complete url, but it didn't works) :

```
<form action="/urlCommandeServ" method="post">
```

And my servlet :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String cat = request.getParameter("categorie");
    Float prix = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("prix"));
    response.sendRedirect("CreerCommande?cat=" + cat+"&prix="+prix);
```

I didn't have any error in eclipse, and the log folder in tomcat is empty. Could you help me ?

EDIT:

There is my error :

[image: Error 404]

I agree for responses about my error on response.sendRedirect, but this is not the real subject of my error :) Even if i erase all of my code on doPost, i have this error, instead of a white page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `<form>` html to

```
<form action="urlCommandeServ" method="post">
```

When you're posting to `/urlCommandeServ` you're asking Tomcat (or your web server) to look for a web application named `urlCommandeServ` which isn't there and hence you get a 404.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include `.jsp` when performing the redirect.

```
response.sendRedirect("CreerCommande.jsp?cat=" + cat+"&prix="+prix);
```

instead of:

```
response.sendRedirect("CreerCommande?cat=" + cat+"&prix="+prix);
```

Also add your contextpath to the url in the form.

```
<form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/urlCommandeServ" method="post">
```

Comment: The redirection will works even if we have .jsp or not. I tried in another project and there are no incidence to the redirection.

Comment: This line isn't the problem, even if i delete this line or changes it to your solution, i still have the 404 error, and the logs folder into Tomcat is empty so..

Comment: I agree with the context path... any possibilities to get the requested path that return 404 in log?

Comment: I bet that is not even hitting the tomcat server

Comment: This is the correct answer. @toshiro92 You need to find out what your context path is (possibly changing it to something simpler) and change your form action url to reflect it.

Comment: I edited my post, and added more informations. I agree about this error, but it isn' the subject. When we have nothing in doPost, you're agree i will see a white page no ? But i still have this error, so this is not the problem. I also changed my server in case of a old project was installed.

Comment: @toshiro Your not even hitting the servlet though.  Add a System.out.println statement in the doPost method, it won't get hit.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use RequestDispatcher?

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("yourPage.jsp");
if (dispatcher != null){
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming he's trying to do a `POST-REDIRECT-GET`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm assuming OP's learning about JSP/Servlet development and think he/she should always do redirect for everything.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No doubt the OP is doing some trial and error. I guess he has to understand the purpose of each dispatch type. Rodrigo, if you add some details about why he would do a `forward`, it might be more helpful to him.

Comment: I concede i have an error on response.sendRedirect, but this is not the subject. I edited my post and added some informations.

Answer (score 0):

See: [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037499/class-not-found-exception-class-fornamecom-mysql-jdbc-driver-in-webservice/10038956#10038956)

"If this code works in your J2SE it means you need to have a JAR file somewhere containing com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class (so called JDBC driver). This JAR needs to be visible in Tomcat. So, I would suggest to place mysql-jdbc.jar at physical location to /WEB-INF/lib directory of your project."